# How to split elements of a list at left white space and assign the left and right to different variables?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, split, variable-assignment

"myList" is a list of lists.I want to split the second element in the internal list so that I can assign to variables to reformat it. 
For instance:
I want to split '100 Free' to '100' and 'Free'
I want to split '0 Not Free' to '0' and 'Not Free'
I want to split '45 Partly Free' to '45' and 'Partly Free'

```
myList = [
   ['Finland', '100 Free', '40', '60'],
   ['Syria', '0 Not Free', '-3', '3'],
   ['Mozambique', '45 Partly Free', '14', '31']
]
```

Desired reformatted Output:

```
Country, Score , Status, pR, cL
Finland, 100, Free, 40, 60
Syria, 0, Not Free, -3, 3
Mozambique, 45, Partly Free, 14, 31
```

Answer (score 0):

I splited the 2nd one as you said, it was like:

```
[['100', 'Free'], ['0', 'Not', 'Free'], ['45', 'Partly', 'Free']]
```

The first one had 2 indexes and the second and the third one was 3 indexes. so I used the try, except.

```
//The code starts here.
myList = [['Finland', '100 Free', '40', '60'], ['Syria', '0 Not Free', '-3', '3'], 
['Mozambique', '45 Partly Free', '14', '31']]
print("Country, Score, Status, pR, cL")
for i in range(0, len(myList)):
    print(myList[i][0], ",", myList[i][1].split()[0], ",", myList[i][1].split()[1], end = " ")
    try:
        print(myList[i][1].split()[2], ",", myList[i][2], ",", myList[i][3])
    except:
        print(",", myList[i][2], ",", myList[i][3])
```